# Einsum in python for a complex loop

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have complex loops in python that I'm trying to "vectorize" to improve computation time. I found the function `np.einsum` allowing it, I managed to use it, but I'm stuck with another loop.

In the following code, I put the loop I managed to "einsumize" (`s1`), and the other one where I didn't.

```py
import numpy as np

Q = 6
P = 24
N = 40

bQ = np.arange(Q)
bP = np.arange(P)
uN = np.arange(N)
t1 = np.arange(P*Q*N).reshape([Q,P,N])
t2 = np.arange(Q*N*Q*N).reshape([Q,N,Q,N])

s1_ = np.einsum('p,q,n,qpn',bP, bQ, uN, t1)
s1 = 0
for p in range(P):
    for q in range(Q):
        for n in range(N):
            s1 += bP[p] * bQ[q] * uN[n] * t1[q,p,n]
print(s1)
print(s1_)
print()

s2_ = np.einsum('p,q,n,m,pnqm', bQ, bQ, uN, uN, t2)
s2 = 0
for p in range(Q):
    for q in range(Q):
        for n in range(N):
            for m in range(N):
                s2 += bQ[q] * bQ[q] * uN[n] * uN[m] * t2[p,n,q,m]
print(s2)
print(s2_)
```

The result of the previous code is

```
13475451600
13475451600

6125547636000
5707354770000
```

The math formula to compute `s1` is : `s1 = \sum_p\sum_q\sum_n bP[p] * bQ[q] * uN[n] * t1[q,p,n]`. And the one to compute `s2` is `s2 = \sum_q\sum_q'\sum_n\sum_n' bQ[q] bQ[q'] uN[n] uN[n'] t2[q,n,q',n']`.

For the *triple* loop, if I well understood how `einsum` works,I tell the different indices of the tensors that will be multiplied, and telling no output indices tell that all will be summed. But it seems not to be working for the *quadruple* loop.

**EDIT :** I saw an answer (which seems to have been deleted), telling that it was just a mistake of index on the quadruple loop... I should have seen it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a typo in your code, you are not using the variable `p` outside of the order 4 tensor.

Try changing

```py
                s2 += bQ[q] * bQ[q] * uN[n] * uN[m] * t2[p,n,q,m]
```

for

```py
                s2 += bQ[p] * bQ[q] * uN[n] * uN[m] * t2[p,n,q,m]
```